# return type after while in a try

Tags: while-loop, try-catch, ocaml, imperative-programming

Almost for the first time I'm trying to write imperative code in ocaml to try to answer a question on this website, but I'm facing a little problem.

```
let f() =
try
  while true do
    ()
  done
with
    _ -> 2
```

He doesn't like this, because he thinks that this function returns unit, as it is in the try block, but the try block returns an int. So it works if I add 3 after "done", but it's really ugly since the 3 is really never returned.

How do you do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `assert false`, which always raises an exception and therefore can be used where any type is expected:

```
let f() =
  try
    while true do
      ()
    done;
    assert false
  with
      _ -> 2
```

Comment: I don't like this too much but I guess it's the prettiest thing we can find. Would it be too hard to ask the type system to realize that a "while true" never finishes and that it could thus have the type 'a ?

Comment: @double_squeeze: the fact that `assert false` has type `'a` is already such an hack in the type system (normal assertions, including `assert 0=1`, have type `unit`). I guess the OCaml developers do not want to have too many special cases like that in the typing algorithm.

Comment: @Virgile: I don't think it's such a hack. It raises an exception, it's normal that it has type 'a. And we could have an additional type, say "nothing", for when a piece of code never returns. You can't say if it returns or not in general, but you know it for a "while true" loop.

Comment: @double_squeeze: don't call it a hack if you don't want to, but the fact is that this is a special case that require to treat `assert false` differently from `assert e` where `e` is any expression of type `bool` beside `false`. That said, in absence of `break`, I agree that `while true` could have benefited from the same special treatment.

Comment: @Virgile oh I didn't know that the other assert bool return unit. That really sucks. I can't see the motivation behind that. Thanks.

Comment: @double_squeeze exactly the same motivation as the request for `while true do ... done` having type `'a`.

Comment: @double_squeeze Well, what would you expect `assert true` to evaluate to except `()`? If you can't tell for sure that the assertion will always be false (and except for `assert false` this is arbitrary complicated), you can't assume that the expression will never return. Thus it's not possible to give it an `'a` type.

Answer (score 4):

- **while** (and **for**) loops in OCaml are expressions that return a result of type **unit**.
- In addition, when you write (**try expr1 with _ -> expr2**), this is an OCaml expression of type **t**, if **expr1** and **expr2** are well typed of type **t** (more complicated with polymorphism)
- But, in your example, **try** branch has type **unit** whereas **with** branch has type **int**. The OCaml compiler is not happy with that.